# Angular2 - how to bind an input to a function within a container in html

Tags: angular

This is an example code:

component.ts file

```
getThirty() {
 return 'width:30%'
}
```

html file

```
<div class="progress-bar" style = "getThirty()">
```

This doesn't work... how do I bind a function to the input?

I've also tried `[style]="getThirty()"` and this still doesn't work..

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you set a variable and bind that.

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried using following approach, it works for me.

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="{{getThirty()}}">
 fhyjhrtjrjrj
</div>
```

Hope This Helps.

Comment: Are you allowed to do that? I tried but didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows

1. in your template:  `<div [style.width]="getThirty">`

2.in your component : public getThirty = 30+'%';

that's it :)